# Nodered node Output for each item in Array of unknown length

Tags: node-red

I have a msg.payload full of an array of items, sometimes 2, sometimes 20.  I need to pass them to a different node that only accepts a single item at a time to process..

I am sure there is something simple but I cant work it out.  Could I please get a pointer?

The best I can come up with is a function which has maybe 30 outputs, and I just pass them all, and sometimes I will be passing null I guess.  But there must be a easier way - what if there was 200..

Answer (score 1):

The `split` node does just that. If `msg.payload` is an array of (say) 20 items, it will split it into 20 messages to be passed on to your different node.

Alternatively, you can use a `function` node if you want, with only one output. Loop around the array and use `node.send(newMsg)` where `newMsg` has a new payload for each item. In this case you should call `node.done()` afterwards, since your function won't be returning a message itself.

Comment: The split node is the right answer here, if you use the function node you need to make sure you preserve any other msg properties in the additional messages. the split node also adds suitable meta data about the total number of messages which can be useful to reassemble the array later if needed.